# how to redirect to current page in joomla 3.x after login

Tags: joomla3.0

I've not so experience in joomla.

I'm facing 2 problems to build a site.

1. How can I redirect user to current page after login?
2. Logged in user is seeing different layout for the pages

Answer (score 0):

Question 1 - You have two options:

**A. If you have the login form vía menu item**, you can see an option called
 **Login Redirect** and **Logout Redirect** in:

**Your menu item** > **Options** Tab

**B. If you are using the Login Module** you can see similar options for **Login**
 and **Logout Redirection**.

Question 2 - Different Layout:

**A.** Check the **Template Style** for your users in:

**Users** > **Manage** > Your User > **Basic Settings** Tab

**B.** In your menu item you also have an option called **Template Style** in the
 **Details** Tab check the default template in the user menu items.

Regards.